# AXIS2 webservice monitoring tools

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I am trying to find tools to monitor AXIS2 webservices. Is there anything readily available? I tried psi-probe. But it didn't provide statistics operation wise. It can provide from application wise. Basically I am looking for below:

1. Show Min/Max/Avg Response Times.
2. Show requst / response counts operations wise.
3. Show session info, if any.

I'm trying to find a solution to quickly integrate, so I can give it off to support people to quickly monitor and zero in on the problematic area asap.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can host axis2 services in [wso2 appserver](http://wso2.com/products/application-server/) and monitor those [stats](http://docs.wso2.org/display/AS520/Access+and+Performance+Statistics)